# PHP Sql injection vulnerable

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote the below script as my very first ever php mysql application.  I am self taught and the code works as intended.  My host thinks it may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks but cannot tell me why or what I should change to make it better.  I'm sure it's not as clean as it could be but if anyone has any suggestions or insight I would certainly appreciate it.

```
<form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform">
      <?php
      $db=mysql_connect ("server",  "*", "*") or die ('I cannot connect  to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("*");
$category_sql="SELECT distinct category FROM Members";
$category_Options="";
$category_result=mysql_query($category_sql) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {

    $category=$row["category"];
    $category_Options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$category\">".$category.'</option>';
}
?>
   <p>
          <SELECT NAME="category"><OPTION VALUE=0>Choose<?=$category_Options?></SELECT>

   </p>
<input name="submit" "id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  $category=$_POST['category'];
  $category=mysql_real_escape_string($category);
  $sql="SELECT category, company, address, city, state, zip, phone, web, addescription, image
  FROM Members
  WHERE category LIKE '$category'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $category2=$row["category"];
        $company=$row["company"];
        $address=$row["address"];
        $city=$row["city"];
        $state=$row["state"];
        $zip=$row["zip"];
        $phone=$row["phone"];
        $web = $row["web"];
        $addescription = $row["addescription"];
        $image = $row["image"];
  echo "<blockquote>";
  if(@file_get_contents($image))
{
  echo "<img src='".$image ."' class='image'/>\n";
}
else
{
}
  echo "<p>\n";
  echo "</br>".$category2 . "\n";
  echo "</br><b>".$company . "</b>\n";
  echo "</br>".$address . "\n";
  echo "</br>".$city . ", ".$state. " ".$zip . "\n";
  echo "</br>".$phone . "\n";
  echo "</br><a href=http://".$web .">".$web ."</a>\n";
  echo "</br>".$addescription . "\n";
  echo "</br><a href=http://www.printfriendly.com style=color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none; class=printfriendly onclick=window.print();return false; title=Printer Friendly and PDF><img style=border:none; src=http://cdn.printfriendly.com/pf-button.gif alt=Print Friendly and PDF/></a>\n";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "</blockquote>"
  ;
 }


  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Please select a Category</p>";
  }
  }
mysql_close($db)
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)? It pretty much covers it.

Comment: There are lots of article to prevent SQL injection. Why not google it ;)

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated, and have been considered obsolete for years. If you learnt from a tutorial that used them then you are almost certainly doing things wrong, as a tutorial old enough to recommend using those functions would also be old enough to be using other bad practices that aren't recommended any more. I suggest finding a site with more up-to-date tutorials to learn from.

Comment: If you are not using some character sets (GBK or BIG-5) you are ok: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/151758
Someone could still make a form (for example using firebug) to replace one of your categories values by "%" which could be a bad thing if you have millions of members.
But as you are learning, you should get good habits as soon as possible: the mysql extension is deprecated in php 5.5 and a prefered way to send SQL queries is by using parameterized queries. PDO is a really good way to do it, you should be able to get a lot of infos about it on Stackoverflow or the php doc.

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL functions are deprecated.  Using the MySQLi functions, and prepared statements, are a better way to protect against sql injection attacks.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT category, company, address, city, state, zip, phone, web, addescription, image FROM Members WHERE category LIKE ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll show the implementation of a PDO connection and how to query with it. Here it goes!
First we create the connection variable with your database credentials. We'll store this connection in `$db`.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "my_database";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try{
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8"; $username, $password, $options);
}catch(PDOException $ex){
   die("Failed to connect: ".$ex->getMessage());
}
```

Now you have a PDO connection stored in `$db` which you can query through. You may want to account for [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) if you're not using PHP 5.4, so keep that in mind.

Otherwise, create your query statement like so..

```
$query = "SELECT category, company, address, city, state, zip, phone, web, addescription, image FROM Members WHERE category LIKE :category"
```

Afterwards, you want to bind the value from the `$_POST['category']` variable (or `$category` since you created that) to the parameter `:category`. Do that like so:

```
$query_params = array( ':category' => $category);
```

Finally, now that you have the statement and the parameters, use the previously created `$db` variable to prepare and execute the statement.

```
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $statement->execute($query_params);
```

Since we're `SELECT`ing data where it could return multiple rows (assuming you have multiple rows within a category), we need to account for that. Grab the rows that the statement returns like so:

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
```

And now you could refer to column headers within each `$row` of the database table by utilizing a foreach statement.

```
$citiesArray = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   if(isset($row['city'])){
       $citiesArray[] = $row['city'];
   }
}
```

Hope that helps out!

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the golden rule of never trusting your users. Never take any raw user input and insert it into a database, as there's a chance that you have left yourself wide open for a security issue.

Your code seems fine. However, do note that MySQL is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and instead you should use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) extension which provide more security.

Maybe that's the reason your host said such thing, but from a quick look on your code it seemed fine to me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the follwoing part in your code

```
$sql = "SELECT category, company, address, city, state, zip,
             phone, web, addescription, image
        FROM Members
        WHERE category LIKE '$category'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

If the parameter $category is read from the GET or POST parameters, it should be [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT category, company, address, city, state, zip,
             phone, web, addescription, image
        FROM Members
        WHERE category LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($category) . "';";
```

If you are doing it this way, the variable cannot be used for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

By the way (like Matthew Johnson said), the procedural mysql extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5. You should better use [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

The OOP way (strongly recommended) would look like:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
$statement = $pdo->prepareStatement(
    "SELECT category, company, address,
            city, state, zip, phone, web,
            addescription, image
     FROM Members
     WHERE category LIKE :category;");
$statement->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$categories = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This is how PHP was done fifteen years ago and it's about time people stopped doing it this way.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post: the procedural way is depracted. I have added to usage of PDO.

Comment: Much improved with an example of how to do it correctly.